# Dealing with 2 models in 1 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models I'm trying to interact with in 1 view. The first model is Room and the second is Availability. 1 Room has many Availabilities.

On 1 Rooms page, I render out availabilities through a partial like this:

```
<% @room.availabilities.where("booking_id is NULL").order("start_time").each_with_index do |a|%>
```

Beside each availability I have a button to delete and update. The delete worked out fine since it was in my loop so I could do something like this.

```
<%= link_to("Delete", availability_path(a.id), method: :delete,  remote: true) %>
```

But I'm having trouble with edit. I'm trying to do it through a modal which doesn't have access to the 'a' variable from the loop. So I'm not sure how to pass in the unique availability to the form

Button:

```
<!-- Edit button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAvailability"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>

<!-- Edit Availability Form -->
<%= simple_form_for @facility.availabilities.find(???), method: :put, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with AJAX. I have an app that has a modal dropdown that lets me toggle pieces of equipment in or out of service with a button in the dropdown. You can use a route that points towards the Availabilities controller that renders a form in the modal. Mine is simple in that it just toggles, but I don't see why you can't use a form. I would move your query out of your view and make a helper that gives you the results of your query in a variable.

I can provide more detail but need to see a lot more of your current code. If you can post your controller and all of your view code for the modal. I don't know understand why you don't have access to the variable you need in the modal? If the modal has an AJAX call you should be able to populate it with any data available to your controllers.

**edit**

Take a look at this: https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals . Be sure and read the links at the end of this article, it has some StackOverflow examples that are spot on. I'm thinking link_to is the way to go:

```
<%= link_to 'Update, availabilities_edit_path(a.id), {:remote => true, 'data-controls-modal' =>  "modal-window", 'data-backdrop' => true, 'data-keyboard' => true} %>
```

This should open a modal and ask the `availabilities#edit` controller for a JS response. Make sure you have an edit action, I don't see one in your controller:

```
availabilities.rb

  def edit
    @availability = Availability.find_by(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
```

So the JS call will cause it to look in the /views/availabilities/ folder for a file called edit.js.erb with content like:

```
$('#editAvailability').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'editForm') %>');
```

In your edit form you you now have the `@availability` instance variable to use in your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @availability, method: :put, remote: true do |f| %>
...
```

So your modal gets built using an AJAX lookup that returns a form built using the needed instance variable. I'm putting this together from stuff I've written and other stuff I've read, so there will probably be some errors and tweaking to get your code working.  Let me know how far this gets you.

Comment: Hey, I put the controller and views here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ExSD06WD1TPuAYsu0XN?p=info

Comment: Hey, it took a while but I seem to have got it working. The issue I'm seeing now though is that the ajax call to get the modal and update the fields with the correct attributes is very slow. Pretty much each call is at least 2 seconds. Otherwise though, thanks a lot, this was a great help.

Comment: What is going on in your web server logs? There's no reason it should be so slow. You should be able to track down the bottleneck. Might need a view in the DB to speed things up. If you want to add the working code to plnkr I can tweak the answer so it is exact. Would help others in the future.

Comment: I turned off `config.assets.debug = false` in developement.rb so that speed things up quite a bit in general. Brings the ajax call wait time to less than 500ms which is a big improvement from 2 seconds

Comment: Ah, that was one thing I hit on in a search. That would make me think that poor performance could still be related to an assets issue. Make sure you aren't loading big stuff like Bootstrap in two different places. Might need to pare down your includes. And if you are seeing a lot of DB calls each time it loads, you might need to put some logic in the models to have the information queried in a more efficient manner.

Comment: I'm so new to this, I'm kind of just focusing on getting the application ready so I haven't been really focusing on performance yet. I'm seeing this http://i.imgur.com/QMIIAYi.png on a page load, it doens't seem excessive to me but I don't know what I'm looking for just yet.

Comment: Well, you can see most things load in less than 1ms. But then `Rendered facilities/show.html.erb within layouts/application (489.8ms)` That's your half a second right there. My first suspect would be in your facilitiesAvailability.html: `<% @facility.availabilities.where("booking_id is NULL").order("start_time").each_with_index do |a|%>`. I try to always pass my view an instance variable that contains the data queried into an array already. That way the data is already collected ( or cached ) for the view rendering.

Comment: Yea, I ended up moving that out into a controller function and simple calling `<% facility_availabilities?.each_with_index do |a|%>` to return the value. I'll keep playing around with it and pay a bit more attention to these numbers in the log so I can try to keep things lean. I'm pretty new to rails so it's going to be a learning process. Thanks a lot  for all your help though. Learned a few new things from your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the information necessary in your update button within your loop like this:

```
<%= link_to("Update", method: :put, remote: true, data: { attr1: a.attr1, attr2: a.attr2 }) %>
```

Then every button knows what entity they are operating for.

Comment: I don't think that would work. I updated the OP. The button on the Rooms page, simple brings up the Model. Can I pass data from that button to the modal form?

Comment: You will have to use javascript to read the data in the DOM element. I don't think it is possible to use :simple_form_for as user interaction since render is a one-time thing when the page is loaded.